# One event works the other does not work

Tags: solidity, events

I have a simple code with 2 events in 2 different functions. However, one event is generated and the second one not.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.9;

/* Contract accepting ethers during 10 minutes */
contract ReceiveEther {

    address receivingAccount;
    uint deadline;
    event EtherReceival(address sender, uint amount);
    event ContractDisposed(string contractName, uint time);

    /*  at initialization, setup the owner */
    function ReceiveEther(address _account) {
        // set the receiving account
        receivingAccount = _account;
        // set the deadline as 10 minutes
        deadline = now + 10 * 1 minutes;
    }   

    /* The function without name is the default function that is called whenever 
       anyone sends funds to a contract */
    function () public payable {
        uint amount = msg.value;
        receivingAccount.send(amount);
        EtherReceival(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

    /* checks if the time limit has been reached and ends the contract */
    function dispose() afterDeadline {
        ContractDisposed("ReceiveEther", now);
        suicide(receivingAccount);
    }
}
```

I deploy it as:

```
// must unlock the account we are creating the contract from so we can use it
personal.unlockAccount(eth.accounts[1],"Node01Account01")
// must set the _account parameter
_account = eth.accounts[1]
// contract code
var receiveether_sol_receiveetherContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":false,"inputs":[],"name":"dispose","outputs":[],"payable":false,"type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"_account","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"type":"constructor"},{"payable":true,"type":"fallback"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"sender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"amount","type":"uint256"}],"name":"EtherReceival","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":false,"name":"contractName","type":"string"},{"indexed":false,"name":"time","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ContractDisposed","type":"event"}]);
var receiveether_sol_receiveether = receiveether_sol_receiveetherContract.new(
   _account,
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
     // configure the event to watch for changes
     receiveether_sol_receiveether.EtherReceival({}, function(error, result){
       if (!error)
         console.log("[Ether received: Sender: " + result.args.sender + ", Amount: " + web3.fromWei(result.args.amount, "ether")+" ether(s)]");
     });
    receiveether_sol_receiveether.ContractDisposed({}, function(error, result){
       if (!error)
         console.log("[Contract " + result.args.contractName + " has been disposed.]");
     });
    }
 })
```

After I deploy and I interact with it:

```
> loadScript("contracts/ReceiveEtherWithLog.js")
null [object Object]
true
> null [object Object]
Contract mined! address: 0xb57df20fad55c6e91d6c525292e075c39bb47855 transactionHash: 0x2abb38d0b6754a1631c1cf6bcfad3bacc869af6cb6a0e23166fb9434cab00624
> var tx = {from:  personal.listAccounts[2], to: "0xb57df20fad55c6e91d6c525292e075c39bb47855", value: web3.toWei(1.0, "ether")}
undefined
> personal.sendTransaction(tx, "Node01Account02")
"0x928be3639e82345b3720841f11d6ac8d06f6bfcc0be34600f85d2a39364d771b"
> [Ether received: Sender: 0x7d6af3000bb220d013a3b02e3dd964f9fac7fa87, Amount: 1 ether(s)]
> receiveether_sol_receiveether.dispose({from: eth.accounts[2]})
"0x6000b524f2a5f03a645c2b7b4b0fda6b9358219004a75ba5b2a1c1105b304766"
>
```

Here I would expect that the `ContractDisposed` event is created and then a log is generated in the console. However, nothing happens.
I don't know the origin of the problem. I don't know if the event is created or not. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible to emit an event from a transaction that does:

```
suicide()
```

Just not compatible with event emission or return values. A calling contract would be able to emit an event for "I killed 0x123" but the victim can't speak.

Just as an FYI, `suicide()` was renamed to `selfdestruct()` in an effort to be more sensitive to personal tragedies individuals have experienced. Just mentioning it to save you the time of wading through docs in search of a definitive clarification. They do the same thing right now but we can expect end-of-support for the deprecated form at some point.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I was thinking that since I create the event before `suicide()`, it should work. According to your explanation, events are created after the function finishes, right?

Comment: Possibly someone can chime in with a protocol-level explanation. Not so much about the sequence of events. Similar to the way throw reverts things that came before. As a developer take-away, selfdestruct() zeros out the contract's current state and the destroyed contract can't talk. Return values and event emissions don't fly.